# How to make educated guess about movement of people through graph?

Tags: optimization, prediction, simulation, spatial, graph-theory

I have data about weekly counts of people on entry points (orange circles on the picture below) and need to make educated guess about their counts at destination points (marked by green stars). I know the average speed (number of hours needed to take the route). People can move in any direction, can make any distance per day, can take few-hour, one-day, or multiple-day trips through the graph. Multiple destination points can be visited per day and per trip. A priori it can be assumed that most trips take less than day, but a small fraction can take longer ones. It can be assumed that entry points are chosen purposefully and that entry points cannot be used as stops during a longer trip. It can be assumed that the destination points are not re-visited per trip if not needed.

[image]

The initial idea that I have is to assign a fraction of all people on entry point to each of the destination points, where size of the fraction is proportional to the shortest distances to the destination points. The problem is that this ignores the fact that going to the most distant destination needs you to visit a number of intermediate points. Simulation can be used to sequentially move people through the graph with some probabilistic criteria for "ending" trip at some point (so length of the trip follows geometric distribution).

I would be grateful for *any* hints about how such educated guess can be made and for providing references that deal with similar problems.

Comment: these type/class of problems canbe solved using operations research methods such as traveling sales man problem/combinatorial optimization.

Comment: @forecaster that is why I used `[optimization]` tag. Travelling salesman was also the thing that came to my mind, but still I'm looking for some hints. The data that I have is very limited and it is almost impossible for me to validate the solution, so I'm looking for different possible solutions to come up with some "safe" estimate.

Comment: what about looking into maxent (maximum entropy) methods?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen still no answer for this one, so feel free to expand the comment into answer.